# Cycles hair and scaling the object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

If I set a hair particle system and then scale the object for some reason,
all the settings I have put in PS are lost.

It does not resemble to original look I've set.

How to scale the object so that PS hair scales along with it ?

EDIT: [hair.blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13451287/hair.blend)

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image/gif/video?

Comment: @JohnRoper , I've updated the post. PS hair is on Plane object. Try to scale it up, down, rotate along z and you'll see it does not retain the shape.

Comment: Scale the mesh in edit mode